# drawImage не работает с переменными класса на js

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте столкнулся с проблемой того, что при передачи аргументов класса в drawImage, консоль ошибок не выдает, но drowImage не срабатывает, вот упрощенный пример кода

```
<canvas id="canvasId"></canvas>
<script>
  class Ss {
    constructor() {
      this.hhh = "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/boy-draws-with-a-brush-a-big-light-bulb-concept-of-innovation-and-picture-id1133176165?k=20&m=1133176165&s=612x612&w=0&h=j7J93Lkm7npuBWfww93Gkg9z4rko2FXJ4ThFGGrVzDE=";
      this.x = 64;
    }
    metod() {
      var image = new Image();
      image.src = this.hhh;
      image.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("canvasId").getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.x, 64);
      };
    }
  }
  const blast = new Ss();
  blast.metod();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, для onlodad функции this будет являться собственная переменная, к которой был применен onload, то есть this=image